# Scope of COUNT(DISTINCT ..) when used with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, distinct

I'm doing something like follows (Example, getting distinct people named "Mark" by State):

```
Select count(distinct FirstName) FROM table
GROUP BY State
```

I *think* the group by query organization is done first, such that the distinct is only relative to each "group by"?  Basically, can "Mark" show up as a "distinct" count in each group?  This would "scope" my distinct expression to the group by rows only, I believe...

Answer (score 0):

This may actually depend on where `DISTINCT` is used.  For example, `SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(` would be different than `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT`.

In this case, it will work as you want and get a count of distinct names in each group (even if the names are not distinct across groups).

Comment: Hum...I'm going to have to try some examples of the order reversed.  Something tells me it is going to only report distinct "count" results?

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct.  `Group by` says, essentially, to take a group of rows and aggregate them into one row (based on the criteria).  All aggregation functions -- including `count(distinct)` -- summarize values in this group.

As a note, you are using the word "scope".  Just so you know, this has a particular meaning in SQL.  The meaning refers to the portions of the query where a column or table alias are understood by the compiler.